# Retrofit 2 returns null in production

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm trying to fix an issue where Retrofit 2 returns null in response. The interesting thing is that in emulator everything works fine, data is received and displayed, but when I build the APK, the same thing crashes with the NullPointerException. I've commented the line where this happens.

My build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Initialize Retrofit:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(<url>)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Interface:

```
@GET(<url>)
Flowable<DataResponse> getDataFromApi(@Query("offset") int offset, @Query("limit") int limit);
```

API call:

```
retrofit
  .getDataFromApi(0, 10)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Subscriber<DataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(DataResponse dataResponse) {
          // HERE I GET NULL IN PRODUCTION   
        }
```

DataResponse POJO:

```
public class ServicesResponse {
  private List<Item> items;

  public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
}
```

ProGuard. I've tried several things, but still no luck. It currently looks like this:

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class javax.annotation.Nullable
-keep interface javax.annotation.Nullable
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
  @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you post NPE stack trace.  Are you using ProGuard (that's typically cause of issues like this when behaviour differs in release build)?

Comment: Yes, forgot the ProGuard. I've updated the original post. The stack trace is basically the nullpointerexception when I try to do anything with the response.

Comment: -keep public class your.package.to.models.** {*;}

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov: it worked! Can't believe the error was there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always keep model classes used by Retrofit from obfuscation. Otherwise AFAIK Gson can't serialize/deserialize Model:

```
-keep public class your.package.to.models.** {*;} 

# or

#-keepclassmembers class your.package.to.models.** {
#    public <methods>;
#    <fields>;
#}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks a lot! I actually removed all the other stuff related to retrofit, okhttp3 and javax annotations, just left -dontwarn javax.annotation.**. Everything seems to be working.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Is this a known issue? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @InamUlHuq it is not an issue and it is unrelated to Retrofit code. It is how Proguard works, it changes names of fields/functions/classes... You need to tell when not to change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  @SerializedName("items") in your POJO and don't disable the ProGuard for models.

```
public class ServicesResponse {
  @SerializedName("items")
  private List<Item> items;

  public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
}
```